# select rows older then column DATETIME - INT value of other column in single query

Tags: mysql, functions, datetime

I have 2 columns in my table:

```
(DATETIME)lastsendattempt
(INT)sendgap
```

I know I can select all rows that have a "lastsendattempt" DATETIME which is older then the current time. But, am I able to use the value of another column to select the rows that are older than the current time - that `sendgap` value ?

I want it all in a single query instead of getting the `sendgap` value in a query and then doing another one with a `datetime` value

Something like...

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastsendattempt <= (2012-04-10 01:30:15)-(INT)sendgap
```

Answer (score 1):

If `sendgap` is the number of seconds, the correct syntax is this

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE lastsendattempt <= (NOW() - INTERVAL sendgap SECOND);
```